# Alternatives for Monitor (Wait, PluseAll) in Async Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, synchronization, task

I implemented Task synchronization using Monitor in C#.
However, I have read Monitor should not be used in asynchronous operation.

In the below code, how do I implement Monitor methods Wait and PulseAll with a construct that works with Task (asynchronous operations).

I have read that SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync and Release methods can help.
But how do they fit in the below sample where multiple tasks need to wait on a lock object, and releasing the lock wakes up all waiting tasks ?

```
private bool m_condition = false;
private readonly Object m_lock = new Object();

private async Task<bool> SyncInteralWithPoolingAsync(            
            SyncDatabase db,
            List<EntryUpdateInfo> updateList)
{           
        List<Task> activeTasks = new List<Task>();

        int addedTasks = 0;
        int removedTasks = 0;
    
        foreach (EntryUpdateInfo entryUpdateInfo in updateList)
        {            
            Monitor.Enter(m_lock);              
    
            //If 5 tasks are waiting in ProcessEntryAsync method                
            if(m_count >= 5)
            {                   
                //Do some batch processing to obtian values to set for adapterEntry.AdapterEntryId in ProcessEntryAsync
                //.......
                //.......
                
                m_condition = true;                 
                Monitor.PulseAll(m_lock); // Wakes all waiters AFTER lock is released                                           
            }               
    
            Monitor.Exit(m_lock);
            
            removedTasks += activeTasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);

            Task processingTask = Task.Run(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        await this.ProcessEntryAsync(
                                entryUpdateInfo,
                                db)
                            .ContinueWith(this.ProcessEntryCompleteAsync)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
                    });

            activeTasks.Add(processingTask);
            addedTasks++;              
       }           
}                   
            


private async Task<bool> ProcessEntryAsync(SyncDatabase db, EntryUpdateInfo entryUpdateInfo)
{
      SyncEntryAdapterData adapterEntry = 
         updateInfo.Entry.AdapterEntries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.AdapterId == this.Config.Id);

      if (adapterEntry == null)
      {
          adapterEntry = new SyncEntryAdapterData()
          {
               SyncEntry = updateInfo.Entry,
               AdapterId = this.Config.Id
          };

          updateInfo.Entry.AdapterEntries.Add(adapterEntry);
       }

       m_condition = false;
       Monitor.Enter(m_lock);           
       while (!m_condition)
       {
          m_count++;
          Monitor.Wait(m_lock); 
       }
  
       m_count--;
       adapterEntry.AdapterEntryId =  .... //Set Value obtained form batch processing
       
       Monitor.Exit(m_lock);
}

private void ProcessEntryCompleteAsync(Task<bool> task, object context)
{
        EntryProcessingContext ctx = (EntryProcessingContext)context;

        try
        {
            string message;
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Logger.Warning("Processing was cancelled");                  
                message = "The change was cancelled during processing";
            }
            else if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                Exception ex = task.Exception;                 
                Logger.Warning("Processing failed with {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message);
                message = "An error occurred while synchronzing the changed.";
            }
            else
            {
                message = "The change was successfully synchronized";

                if (task.Result)
                {
                   //Processing
                   //...
                   //...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Info(
                "Caught an exception while completing entry processing. " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? Monitor is a fairly low level construct that is rarely used directly, and it looks quite odd to have it mixed with high level asynchronous based code. Especially when said code does not look like it actually is asynchronous. I would expect there to be higher level synchronization primitives you can use for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree with Jonas. Unless you've left some code out, the compiler will be warning you that the methods are not using `await` and thus `async` is unnecessary. The `async` keyword doesn't make your method asynchronous, it just enables the use of `await`. You're also missing `return` statements, so it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @JonasH That's correct. This is kind of psuedo code to demonstrate what I like to achieve. I do not want to use Monitor but need an alternative construct to achieve functionality similar to Monitor.Wait and Monitor.PulseAll for asynchronous  method in this sample code.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have been asked to make changes in an existing tool which uses  async. I am looking for an alternative to Monitor.Pulse to achieve  similar functionality  in asynchronous  method.

Comment: I think I might be able to use AsyncMonitor by Stephen Cleary to implement Monitor in asynchronous method. See https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncMonitor